# Change button text when onclick

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, innerhtml

I've this line of code

```
<?php 
$STRING .= '<a href="#" onclick="changeText(this)" class="btn btn-info btn-lg"></a>';
?>

<script>
function changeText(id) {
id.innerHTML = "Ooops!";
}
</script>
```

which works fine and the button text changes to Oooops

I want the button text to change to the output of

```
 $data = get_user_meta( $authorID, 'cellno', true);
```

I change the value of

```
id.innerHTML = "Ooops!";
```

to

```
id.innerHTML = "$data = get_user_meta( $authorID, 'cellno', true)";
```

or

```
id.innerHTML = "$data";
```

but it doesn't work :(, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
this is the where I took the function of data

```
 $data = get_user_meta( $authorID, 'cellno', true);
        if(strlen($data) > 0){ 
        echo "<span><i class='fa fa-phone'></i> <a href='phone:".$data."' rel='nofollow' target='_blank'>Mobile</a> </span>"; 
        }
```

does it change a thing?

the $data is from another file :D

Comment: doesn't work, the button text changed to data$ i want the text to display the value of $data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something you shouldn't actually do, because you have inline javascript and a `<script>` tag being outputted by php. You should have your javascript in separate files.

But here's how to fix what you're trying to do:

```
<?php 
$STRING .= '<a href="#" onclick="changeText(this)" class="btn btn-info btn-lg"></a>';
$data = get_user_meta( $authorID, 'cellno', true);
?>

<script>
function changeText(id) {
id.innerHTML = <?php echo $data;?>;
}
</script>
```

Comment: still nothing happens when i click the button

Comment: What is the value of $authorID?

Comment: $authorID = $_GET['author']

Comment: Ok. After the page loads, in the src what does it say id.innerHTML is equal to? Are you getting any js errors in the console?

Comment: function changeText(id) {
    id.innerHTML = ""
 } why is it emtpy!!

Comment: If your code is exactly what my original answer is, it's empty because $data resolved to "". You should look into your get_user_meta call and see what it's giving you back. That's where your problem is.

Comment: Thanks flareartist you guide me to the right direction, all fixed :)

Comment: Great! :) glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

```
id.innerHTML = "<?php echo $data = get_user_meta( $authorID, 'cellno', true); ?>";
```

or

```
id.innerHTML = "<?php echo $data; ?>";
```